# In Jekyll, How can I judge whether a post used excerpt_separator or not

Tags: jekyll, jekyll-extensions, jekyll-bootstrap

In my index page, I want to show this:

If a post is short, I will not set the excerpt_separator to make it show the full content, it will display as the same as the single post page.
if a post is long, I will set excerpt_separator in the article, I want to show the excerpt in the post.

In the posts loop of index page,The show template is different between whole article and excerpt,like ellipsis and 'read more' link. So I need to know whether the excerpt separator is used in the current post.How can I judge this,thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can test your `post.content` like this :

```
{% if post.content contains site.excerpt_separator %}
```